# JavaScript- How to display read-only star rating in AngularJS dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

In my application I have an HTML page in which different food items of a store are listed. Again when a single item is clicked the entire details of that particular item is shown - one of the attributes is **"Star Rating"** of the item.

I have 2 controllers regarding this - one `FoodItem` controller & another `FoodItemDetails` controller. Likewise I have 2 templates for each controller - `FoodItems.html` & `FoodItemDetails.html`

In `FoodItemController` I am fetching the details of all food items from the **SQLite Database** using -

```
$scope.foodlists= foodListData;
```

where `foodListData` is an array in the `fetchFood()` function which contains all details of all foods.

Then when a single food item is clicked in `FoodItems.html`

I am setting the attribute values of that particular food using

```
FoodFactory.setSelectedFoodData(tappedFood);


function setSelectedFoodData(data){              
    selectedFood = data;              // where selectedFood is new variable
};

function getSelectedFoodData(data){             
    return selectedFood;       
};
```

In the `FoodItemDetails` Controller, I am calling the getter method &

```
$scope.FoodItem = FoodFactory.getSelectedFoodData();
```

Now in this `$scope.FoodItem` I have the star rating for the specific food item. 
I want to render that star rating in my FoodItemDetails.html.

The star rating will be read-only. The rating cannot be clicked & updated.

`$scope.FoodItem.starRating` - this contains the food rating for the individual food item. I am not able to bind this data `FoodItemDetails.html`.

I can easily bind the other attributes but unable to bind the star rating.
I cannot use jQuery in this application, I can only use Vanilla JS and Angular v1

[image: The star rating I want to have]

[image: The star rating I am getting now]

**The first image is the required star & 2nd one is the one I am getting right now**

**Functionality wise Saurabh Agarwal's answer is perfect. But I want to have the the styling of the star according to specification. I basically want hollow and filled stars and the 1st image is what I am looking for**

Comment: avoid **overusing** bold text

Comment: It may be a scope related problem, can you post some code?

Comment: @Aayushi Jain No it is not like that , if a food item has rating 3 or say 4 I can easily display that in words but the problem is that I have to display that in stars not in words

Comment: @Yogesh Mistry i have agreed to your view. Help me with solution if you can. If a food item has rating 3 or say 4 I can easily display that in words but the problem is that I have to display that in stars not in words

Comment: is `$scope.FoodItem.starRating` holding an `integer` value?

Comment: @Yogesh Mistry  in JSON it is like - "starRating": "4" . From that I am storing in SQLite DB and then fetching in FoodItem Controller.

Comment: if you are getting the rating value and you are finding just to display that in *stars*, you will need to create a function that htmlize the integer/float value of rating into stars. If this is the case, are you finding difficulties in htmlize the rating?

Comment: @Yogesh Mistry yes that is exactly the problem. I can easily display which item got 3 or which got 4 in words , but in html I have to show it as stars - {{foodItem.starRating}} this can be easily shown in words but I have to show that as stars in my application

Comment: @msm0204, check the answer below. hope it helps

Comment: @msm0204 anything wrong with my answer? did you check the plnkr link?

Comment: @Yogesh Mistry I used Saurabh's answer as it felt it is slightly easier. However can with help me with the CSS thing in my updated question.The first image in the question section is the required star & 2nd one is the one I am getting right now

Functionality wise both answers are perfect. But I want to have the the styling of the star according to specification. I basically want hollow and filled stars and the 1st image is what I am looking for

Comment: have you checked the plnkr? i've styled it according to your 1st image.

Comment: @msm0204 did you check that? You can just reuse the function 'addStars' that I've created in the plnkr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working on this around one hour I found that you are getting `$scope.FoodItem.starRating = "4"` which is a string so you need to convert it to Number, Try this solution Hope it will work for you..

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.1/angular.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope) {
   $scope.FoodItem = {};
   $scope.FoodItem.starRating = "4";//this is what you are getting from db
   //you need to conver it to number
   // $scope.FoodItem.starRating = Number($scope.FoodItem.starRating);
   $scope.starRatingData = [{
    id:1,
    colored : 'red'
   },{
    id:2,
    colored : 'red'
   },{
    id:3,
    colored : 'red'
   },{
    id:4,
    colored : 'red'
   },{
    id:5,
    colored : 'red'
   }];
   for (var i = 0; i < $scope.FoodItem.starRating; i++) {
    $scope.starRatingData[i].colored = 'blue';
   }

  });
 </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
 <span ng-repeat="data in starRatingData">
  <span ng-style="{color: data.colored}">&#9734;</span>
 </span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: functionality wise perfect. But can you please hep man with some styling. I want to have the the styling of the star according to specification. I have uploaded 2 images in the Question Section on - the type of stars I am getting now & the type of stars I want. I basically want hollow and fillled stars. Please look the updated question section

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_ref_glyph_star&stacked=h

Comment: I am not using bootstrap in this application , just plain CSS

Comment: I have already upvoted and accepted your answer , please help me with the CSS thing if you can , plain CSS , no bootstrap

Comment: Yes Lea Verou's fiddle is perfect , but how to combine her CSS with your answer

Comment: i have accepted your answer and upvoted you. I am a new user in stackoverflow so they are not showing my upvote

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `for` loop to build html, and `ng-bind-html` to bind/render the generated html (Note: inject `$sce` service). Check this **[plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/LjasYe2GiTIy2NYbx1Wg?p=preview)**. (I've used `input` for you to try out whether it's generating required number of stars or not. Feel free to style your stars as per your choice.)

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks mate. If I had the option to mark both of your answers (you & Saurabh's) as accepted I would have done that. But that is not possible to mark 2 answers as accepted for the same question

Comment: @msm0204 It's ok. No problem. Good that you found my answer useful.